# Check if it a valid url(both relative and absolute)

Tags: url

I would like to check if an url(http or https) is valid. Is there a good way to do it? I think the hard part is validating a relative url. I checked multiple posts but could not find a good answer.

Edit my question to contain more details:
I would like to validate the url in two steps:

1. validate if it is a absolute url(should not be to hard to find it online)
2. validate if it is a relative url. for the relative url, I only want to validate the 'path to resource', 'parameter', 'anchor' part, no need to worry about the 'authority' part according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#authority

Comment: do you mean  the regular expression of the URL ?

Comment: Yeah, it is an common option by providing the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried following:

**REGEX absolute Path URL JavaScript**: `^((http|https)\:\/\/(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/ig`

**REGEX absolute and relative Path URL JavaScript**: `^((http|https)\:\/\/(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})|((\/)?\S\s?)+$`

Comment: @bunny, included relative path also